# Why is it called a 51% attack if you need 2/3 of total stake in Proof of Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, attacks, economics, ethereum-design

Validation schemes require 2/3 of total stake to agree on the next block in proof of stake, so, if I'm a bad actor, outpacing honest validators requires 2/3 of total stake.

Yet, attacks from malicious attackers are still called (per Vitalik) [51% attacks](https://ethresear.ch/t/responding-to-51-attacks-in-casper-ffg/6363). What's going on here? Please feel free to explain the mechanism back to me technically -- I'm guessing my first sentence is wrong at the end, though it's not clear to me why.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean precisely by *outpacing*?

51% attacks are a specific type of attack which require a majority of malicious agents to jeopardize the protocol.

Often in PoS setup you will see the threshold of 2/3 of honest validator  because otherwise, with more than 1/3 of malicious agents you could reach consensus on 2 different things at the same time.